# How to get passport nodejs session value

Tags: node.js, session, passport.js

I want to use session value

but I don't know how to get session values.

I tried type console.log

```js
var aaa = req.session;
var bbb = req.session.passport;
var ccc = req.session.passport.user;
```

aaa,bbb,ccc is can get the value.
result is (console)

```js
//aaa
passport : { user:[ [Object] ] } }

//bbb
{ user:
[{ no : 1, id : aaa, pw : 123 }]

//ccc
[{ no : 1, id : aaa, pw : 123 }]
```

then, I can not get no,id,pw value...

I tried it like this.

then, I can not get no,id,pw value...

I tried it like this.

```js
var ddd = req.session.passport.user[0].value;
```

It doesn't work.

This is my code.
Is there anybody how to solve it.

```js
    passport.use('login', new LocalStrategy({
        usernameField : 'email',
        passwordField : 'pw',
        passReqToCallback : true
    },function(req, email, pw, done) { mysql.select('select * from MYTABLE where email ="'+email+'" and pwd = "'+pw+'"', function (err, data){
            // below code is working. 
            console.log(data[0].no);

            if(data.length < 1){
              console.log('fail');
              return done(null, false);
            }else {
              console.log('success');
              console.log(data);
              return done(null, data);
            }
            if(err){
              res.redirect('back');
         }
        });
     }
    ));
```

```js
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {

 //console.log("123123");
 var aaa = req.session;
 var bbb = req.session.passport;
 var ccc = req.session.passport.user;
 console.log(aaa);
 console.log(bbb);
 console.log(ccc);
 console.log("++++");
    //var ddd = req.session.passport.user[0].value;
    //var eee = req.session.passport.user.value;
    //var fff = req.session.passport.user.no.value;
    // ddd eee fff isn't work.
 
       res.render('front/login_test', {});
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have any key named "value" in the user object. Try with:

```
var no = req.session.passport.user[0].no;
var id = req.session.passport.user[0].id;
var password = req.session.passport.user[0].pw;
```